# Implementation of Spring Security 3.1 across multiple domains, service bus and applications

Tags: java, spring-security, cross-domain, resttemplate

I am trying to find a good way to implement Spring Security 3.1 across all my applications and my service bus.

Service Bus:
REST-services talking with the DB. This is also where all the user information is coming from.

Other applications (war's):
I want to be able to have multiple application stationed at different servers, all authenticating users and talking with the Service Bus through Spring's RestTemplate.

The problem is that the user SessionContext created by Spring Security on the Service Bus is useless when the login call is made via RestTemplate from another domain.
Also I dont want to keep sending the username and password for every call that I'm making to service bus, and then have that look it up in the DB every time.
One time per session should be enough.

I would love to hear your suggestions on how I could go about to implement this.
How do they do it in the Enterprice world?
I've been thinking about CAS, LDAP and even implementing it with Atlassian Crowd, but it seems like such an unnecessary effort.